# Gitlab error "codequality artifact not found"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline with the code quality report (I can load and view this report):
[image]

But I see a message linked to this pipeline in the merge request

> Failed to load codeclimate report

the tooltip is:

> Base pipeline codequality artifact not found

[image]

When can I get the reason of it?

Job description:

```
code-quality:
  stage: test
  image: local-docker-hub-cache/docker:19.03.1
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.1-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - iamge="local-docker-hub-cache/codeclimate:0.85.18"
    - docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
    - docker pull ${iamge}
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD" --volume ~/.m2:/home/root/.m2 --volume "$PWD":/code --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc ${iamge} analyze -f json > codeclimate.json
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: codeclimate.json
```

Comment: could you copy in your question the part of the gitlab-ci where you define the artifact report ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I added ci job description in my question

Answer (score 4):

[Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1335677/vladimir) I also ran into this problem. As it turned out, this is not a mistake. It is described in detail [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215279). In short, in order for this widget to work, you need to launch a pipeline with a code climate job on the target branch of the request. As I understand it, this is due to the fact that the widget displays data not about the current state of the branch, but about the state of the code in comparison with the target branch.

Comment: yes I saw that issue and tried to run job on master branch before but it didn't help me

Comment: I also sometimes get this error after adding into my project. One reason as i understand is that the target master branch is outdated, example you merge anything into master. I ran my pipleline on master and after that codelimate widget work fine for this merge request.

Comment: I execute on target, more for me, this think not work, My target is branch main, I execute in main, but not work! Can you run normal there?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when a codequality report was created in the base branch for the later commit than your branch and the base branch have in common.

Try to rebase your feature branch against the branch you are creating a merge request to, and force-push it.

More information [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215279#note_998380512).